# Checking if an annotation is of a specific type

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, instanceof, isinstance

I am using reflection to see if an annotation that is attached to a property of a class, is of a specific type. Current I am doing:

```
if("javax.validation.Valid".equals(annotation.annotationType().getName())) {
   ...
}
```

Which strikes me as a little kludgey because it relies on a string that is a fully-qualified class-name. If the namespace changes in the future, this could cause subtle errors.

I would like to do:

```
if(Class.forName(annotation.annotationType().getName()).isInstance(
     new javax.validation.Valid()
)) {
   ...
}
```

But `javax.validation.Valid` is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Is there a way to simulate `instanceof` (or basically use `isInstance`) against an interface or an abstract class?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Are you just looking for

```
if (annotation.annotationType().equals(javax.validation.Valid.class)){}
```

?

Answer (score 25):

Or even simpler:

```
if (annotation instanceof Valid) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I think this answer should be higher. If you just want to see if an Annotation instance is of a particular type, just use instanceOf, as it's more straightforward than doing annotation.annotationType().equals(javax.validation.Valid.class)

Comment: Just an observation, this will be always false if the programmer forgets to annotate the @interface with `@Retention(value=RUNTIME)`

Answer (score 13):

Just for completeness' sake, another possibility is

```
if (this.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyCustomAnnotation.class)) {
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I guess I should have done a little more research before posting the question. I discovered that I could use [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

if(Valid.class.isAssignableFrom(annotation.annotationType())) {
   ...
}
```

This seems to do the job. I'm not sure if there are any caveats to using this approach, though.

Comment: It's kind of overkill since it's illegal to extend an annotation anyway.  Don't know if there's any meaningful performance penalty compared to plain equals.

Comment: @Affe Saw your solution - I wasn't aware that you could simply do a an `.equals` or an `==` on `.class`! Thanks for that. I was under the impression that using `.class` simply compares the `Class` objects and not the actual types.

Comment: The class is effectively a singleton.  It is guaranteed that there is only one instance of the Class object for a given Type per classloader, so you can compare them that way in java.

Answer (score 4):

Since an annotation is just a class, you can simply use an == compare:

```
if (annotation.annotationType() == Valid.class) { /* ... */ }
```