# What is Annotation#annotationType() good for?

Tags: java, annotations

The interface Annotation specifies a method

```
Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType()
```

which has a zero-information<sup>1</sup> [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#annotationType--). I wonder what it is good for. All I could find is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3348363/581205), but it's not actually needed there (as the two top answers below the accepted one shows).

---

It allows us to use

```
a.annotationType().equals(MyAnnotation.class)
```

but

```
a instanceof MyAnnotation
```

does the same job... except when `a` is an instance of a class implementing multiple annotations - but have anyone ever seen such a beast?

If `a` is an instance of `class A implements MyAnnotation, YourAnnotation`, then the two above tests are not equivalent, but the question is which one is better...

<sup>(*) It's like stating that `getX()` returns `x`.</sup>

Comment: There is now [JDK-8245620](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8245620) which requests improving the documentation

Comment: JDK-8245620 is now marked as "Won't Fix" for JDK 15, but is fixed in JDK 16.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's like `getClass()`, except due to the way annotations are implemented at runtime, `getClass()` frequently returns a nonsense type for annotation instances.

`annotationType()` returns "the right thing" -- the reflective type of the annotation, not some nonsense runtime type.

Compare `Enum.getDeclaringClass()`, which returns the "right thing" for an enum constant, whereas `myEnumConstant.getClass()` may return a synthetic subtype of the enum.

Comment: Now I understand... comparison to the `Enum` helped. If I ever want a `Map<Class<? extends Annotation>, Whatever>`, then the "real" class is needed.

Comment: Yup.  I frequently pass around `ClassToInstanceMap<Annotation>`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

One reason to use annotationType() is if your annotations are implemented using Proxy classes. Object.getClass() would return the proxy class whereas you may want the underlying "real" implementation class.

There are various examples of this, particularly when dependency injection or other heavyweight reflection is involved.